# Intreceptor refresh page after form submit

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using this code:

https://www.illucit.com/blog/2016/03/angular2-http-authentication-interceptor/

Problem is on submit my page refreshs anyone know how to solve it?

When I remove intreceptor:

```
{
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router) => new HttpInterceptor(xhrBackend, requestOptions, router),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router]
    }
```

It works fine... With intreceptor it not hit API just post method inside intreceptor and do refresh...

Comment: Most likely it's caused by your form markup. Could you post the snippets where you use the form?

Comment: It's not... Because when I remove intreceptor it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is on submit my page refreshs anyone know how to solve it?

You need to capture the `submit` event on the form and preventDefault on it, otherwise the page reloads.